# Parsed date in URL isn't always available (triggers blank screen)

Tags: php, parsing, url

I'm trying to parse data (for filtering) from an URL. I want to be able to use http://domain.com/page.php?startDate=20150101&endDate=20150927. In this example, data is used/visible/calculated from 1 January till 27 September.

When the endDate is entered/changed, that date is properly used in a filter. If it's not entered todays date should be used (but that's where it goes wrong). For that I use the following code:

```
    $endDateFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', htmlspecialchars($query['endDate']));
    $endDate = $endDateFormat->format('Y-m-d'); // change YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD for MySQL.

    if (empty($endDate)) {
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d'); // Use todays date if date is not entered.
    } elseif ($endDate >= date('Y-m-d')) {
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d'); // Use todays date if date is newer than today.
    }
```

For an unknown reason the endDate *must* be added in the URL. If it isn't used, the page is blank. If entered, the code works as supposed: when you use 31-12-2015 as endDate it is automatically corrected to today (you cannot get data from the future, of course) and when you use a date earlier than today that date is used. I verified this by checking the calculations and simply an echo from $endDate.

I don't know how to proceed now to prevent a blank page. The purpose is to use todays date as endDate if you get at http://domain.com/page.php (and thus endDate is empty/NULL/not in the URL).

This issue also appears with the startDate, but I'm quite sure it has the same cause.

Comment: I would assume that `$endDateFormat` is not an object if no date is specified. Therefore you call a method on a non-object which is a syntax error. You should check for the error in your http servers error log file (you _always_ should do that if you have an issue!). Why trying to _guess_ what the error _might be_, if you can look into that file and _read_ what the error _is_.

Comment: I've tried to read the logs, sorry for not mentioning that. Unfortunately the information in that was way too limited (just an 'error in line #'). That's why my hope was on you guys.

Comment: I doubt that, sorry. Apart from the fact that the precise line number is already much more information than you gave here I am quite sure it mention _what_ type of error occurred. That tells you what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I've started from scratch (yet again) and found the solution that worked for me with less code. Not sure why I didn't find it sooner or what went wrong with the earlier 'restarts', but the following works as I want to:

```
        $endDate = htmlspecialchars($query['endDate']);
    if (empty($endDate)) {
        $endDate = date('Ymd');
    } elseif ($endDate >= date('Ymd')) {
        $endDate = date('Ymd');
    }
```